# Getting mutable array of dictionaries then adding objects in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, swift2, nsdictionary

I'm translating two different apps from Swift to Objective - C and one thing I'm hung up on is a global property of an array of mutable dictionaries.

Here is the syntax and Swift and the code where the objects are added,

**1st app** (adding places to a dictionary for a map app)

declared at top of class

```
var places = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
```

objects added

```
places.append(["name":"Taj Mahal","lat":"27.175277","lon":"78.042128"])
```

**2nd app** (check to see if a userID on parse is following another user)

declared at top of class

```
var isFollowing = ["":false]
```

objects added

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

                            if let objects = objects {

                                if objects.count > 0 {

                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = true

                                } else {

                                    self.isFollowing[user.objectId!] = false

                                }
                            }
```

To do this in Objective-C is it necessary to set up an NSObject subclass with an initWithDictionary method?

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

No you won't need to create a custom class to do this.

Create the class-level array by defining this in the `SomeClass.m` file:

```
static NSMutableArray *_places = nil;
```

Use a singleton-pattern to initialize and retrieve it:

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)places
{
    if (!_places)
        _places = [NSMutableArray new];
    return _places;
}
```

Add to it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *places = [SomeClass places];
[places addObject: @{
    @"name" : @"Taj Mahal",
    @"lat" : @(27.175277),    // Note: NSNumber, not NSString
    @"lon" : @(78.042128)     // ditto
}];
```

The second app doesn't need a global array by the look of it; simply a `@property` containing the user-id:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@property NSUInteger followingUserId;
@end
```

And then set/compare the user-id as necessary:

```
NSUInteger incomingUserId = ...;
if (incomingUserId != self.followingUserId) {
    // Set new user-id?
    self.followingUserId = incomingUserId;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try!